# Will access node become the bottleneck in TimescaleDB for horizontal scaling?

Tags: time-series, timescaledb

In a multi-node deployment of TimescaleDB, a database can assume the role of either an access node or a data node. According to [TimescaleDB doc](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/overview/core-concepts/scaling/#multi-node-timescaledb-and-distributed-hypertables), clients interact with the distributed hypertable all through the access node, including the data insertion operation. This means that TimescaleDB access node will be the bottleneck when the write traffic increases.  Any solution on address this issue and making TimescaleDB support 10x write traffic of a single access node?

Answer (score 2):

We have internally built PoC for smart clients to write directly to data nodes, and other approaches to further scale out in the future.  Just on the roadmap for future =)

(TimescaleDB person)

Comment: thank you Mike!  look forward to the smart client.

Comment: Hi Mike,any news of the smart-client? I worry about the single access node bottleneck issue too.